# How can I change this code to a servlet page with action control from a jsp page?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

I need this java code to be run in a servlet page. So that when I submit a button in jsp it should display the values.

Below given is a java code which have a main function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        try { 
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("userData.xlsx"));       
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);            
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator(); 
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) { 
                Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); 

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) { 
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); 
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) { 
                    case NUMERIC: 
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()); 
                        break; 
                    case STRING: 
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());                            
                        break; 
                    } 
                } 
                System.out.println(""); 
            } 
            file.close(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } }}
```

I need to run this code in a servlet and give its url in a jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your query, that on a http get request, read the excel file's first sheet and return the records.

You can use spring's web mvc framework, where you may perform your reading excel file action in controller and return the excel view.

I hope this [tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-excel-view-example-apache-poi-and-jexcelapi) may help.

Comment: Can't we do it without using spring?

Comment: To serve any http request in Java you need servlet. Spring's web mvc  framework provides the support.

Comment: _Can't we do it without using spring?_ - you can, start e.g. here:  https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-servlets